Dynamic Date Filter based on end-user choice
I hopy you can help me.
I have the following table named Table1. This table contains a lot of information about sales and includes two date columns: "Period1" and "Period2".
In my Power BI report, I want to have two filters:
The first filter should require the end-user to choose between "Period1" or "Period2".
The second filter should display a date hierarchy based on the selected period. If the user selects Period1, the filter should show all the dates from the "Period1" column, and if Period2 is selected, it should show the dates from the "Period2" column.
I have created the following tables - however it does not work when I try to add the filters/slicers.
New table:
DateSelection = 
DATATABLE(
    "DateOption", STRING,
    { 
        {"Period1"},
        {"Period2"}
    }
)

New table:
DateTable = CALENDAR(
    MIN(MIN('Table1'[Period1]), MIN('Table1'[Period2])), 
    MAX(MAX('Table1'[Period1]), MAX('Table1'[Period2]))
)

Calculated Column in Table1:
SelectedDateColumn = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE(DateSelection[DateOption]) = "Period1", Table1[Period1],
    SELECTEDVALUE(DateSelection[DateOption]) = "Period2", Table1[Period2]
)

Thanks in advance!

Can you provide some data ?

Calculated Tables and Calculated Columns get calculated during dataset refresh time and are static after that. They will not change during report run/view time and will not be affected by slicers and user interaction.

You can solve this with Field Parameters.
Example table:



Period 1
Period 2




01/01/2024
01/03/2024


02/01/2024
02/03/2024


03/01/2024
03/03/2024


...
...


29/01/2024
29/03/2024


30/01/2024
30/03/2024


31/01/2024
31/03/2024



Select New Paramter > Fields under Modeling tab, and add your two Period columns...

And feel free to select Add slicer to this page at the bottom of dialog window.

Change this slicer to be Single select.
The trick here now is to add a Table visual and add Period Selector[Period Selector] to the table.
Now switch this Table visual to the Slicer visual, and you should be good to go.



Awesome - exactly what I need.
I have some questions. How did you make the second table. The visual where the periods change?
Can you change the dates to be in a hierarchy?

I figured it out! Wow - what a trick in point 2! THANKS!!!
